# POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/2/flagged 422 (Unprocessable Content)

Tags: laravel, flutter

i want to post both laravel and flutter code....I have confirmed that the laravel api is working perfectly fine  sing postman but when i get to fluter i get the error 422...unprocessable content//below is laravel code for controller ,route and model class//class FlagController extends Controller

```
/class FlagController extends Controller
{


    public function Flag(Request $request,$id)
    {

        $attrs = $request->validate([
            'reason' => 'required|string',
            'body' => 'required|string'
        ]);



        $image = $this->saveImage($request->image, 'posts');



        $post = post::find($id);

        if (!$post) {
            return response([
                'message' => 'not found'
            ], 403);
        }

        Flag::create([
            'post_id' => $id,
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,

            'reason' => $attrs['reason'],
            'body' => $attrs['body'],
            'image' => $image,

        ]);
        return response([
            'message' => 'post flagged'
        ], 200);

    }

    public function getFlag(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $flagId = $id;


        $flag = Flag::find($flagId);
        // $postId = $id;
        //$postId = $request->input('post_id');
        $userId = $request->input('user_id');
        $reason = $request->input('reason');

        // Query database for flagged post
        //$post = Post::find($postId);

        // Return post details along with flagging reason
        return response()->json([
            'post' => $flag,
            'reason' => $reason
        ]);
    }
    public function getAllFlaged()
    {

        return response([
            'posts' => Flag::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()
        ], 200);
    }
}
//controller//<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\User;

class Flag extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'post_id',
        'reason',
        'body',
        'image'
    ];
}//model//<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\User;

class Flag extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'post_id',
        'reason',
        'body',
        'image'
    ];
}//Route::post('/posts/{id}/flagged', [FlagController::class, 'Flag']);

// get single flagged post
Route::get('/posts/{id}/flagged', [FlagController::class, 'getFlag']);
// get all flaged posts
Route::get('/flagged', [FlagController::class, 'getAllFlaged']);
///the following are the flutter codes///class Flagged {
  int? id;
  String? reason;
  int? post_id;
  int? user_id;
  String? image;
  String? body;

  Flagged(
      {this.id,
      this.reason,
      this.post_id,
      this.user_id,
      this.image,
      this.body});

// map json to Flagged model
  factory Flagged.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Flagged(
      id: json['id'],
      reason: json['reason'],
      post_id: json['post_id'],
      user_id: json['user_id'],
      image: json['image'],
      body: json['body'],
    );
  }
}//model class for flagged//Future<ApiResponse> flagged(int postId, String reason, String body,String image) async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response =
        await http.post(Uri.parse('$postsUrl/$postId/flagged'), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
     },
      body: image != null
            ? {
                'body': body,
                'image': image,
                'reason': reason,
              }
            : {'body': body,
            'reason':reason});
    // body: {
    //   'reason': reason,
    //   'body': body,
    // });

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        break;

      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}
//post service class// void _handleFlagPost(
      int postId, String reason, String body, String image) async {
    ApiResponse response = await flagged(postId, reason, body, image);
    if (response.error == null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('Post flagged successfully'),
      ));
    } else if (response.error == unauthorized) {
      // Handle unauthorized error
      // For example, log out the user
      logOut().then((value) => {
            Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),
                (route) => false)
          });
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('${response.error}'),
      ));
    }
  }//   PopupMenuButton(
                            child: const Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.flag,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                )),
                            itemBuilder: (context) => [
                              const PopupMenuItem(
                                // ignore: sort_child_properties_last
                                child: Text('violate'),
                                value: 'violate',
                              ),
                              const PopupMenuItem(

                                  // ignore: sort_child_properties_last
                                  child: Text('irrelevant'),
                                  value: 'irrelevant')
                            ],
                            onSelected: (String value) {
                              print('state');
                              if (value == 'irrelevant') {
                                _handleFlagPost(post.id ?? 0, 'irrelevant',
                                    post.body ?? '', post.image ?? '');
                              } else if (value == 'violate') {
                                _handleFlagPost(post.id ?? 0, 'violate',
                                    post.body ?? '', post.image ?? '');
                              }
                            },
                          )
```

below is the error code am getting from the console

```
{
    "message": "The body field is required.",
    "errors": {
        "body": [
            "The body field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

the laravel api is working perfectly on laravel I have tested on postman

Comment: Did you check some logs or Telescope so that you can compare inputs for working and non working example?

Comment: check your request data , all data is comming or not , this error  indicate the validation error